# Javascript - How to change Div alignment when secondary div's visiablity is set to 'none'

Tags: javascript

I have 2 Divs, side by side. By default, only the left one shows, and it centered in the page content horizontally. But when the user click's a button on the first div, it would slide to the left, and show the other div. 
I already have the visibilty setup. But The problem is, I need my js to detect that the div's `display:none` attribute, and adjust the first div accordingly (`float:left` or `float:right`)
If possible, a fiddle would be nice also.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you if I got your problem completely:-

HTML

```
<div id="left">
    <button onclick="showDiv()">Show</button>    
</div>
<div id="right">

</div>
```

JS

```
   function showDiv(){
    var leftDiv = document.getElementById('left');
    var rightDiv = document.getElementById('right');
    leftDiv.style.float  = 'left';
    rightDiv.style.float = 'right';
    rightDiv.style.display = 'block';
}
```

CSS

```
div{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background:gray;
margin:10px;
}
#left{
    float:right;
}

#right{
    display:none;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/qvwpp/1/)